# ¿Cómo pasar datos de una estructura a otra?

Tags: c

tengo que resolver este problema que me da estas 2 estructuras

```
typedef struct {
   char ciudad[N];
   double datos[365];
   int n_datos;
} T_TEMP;

typedef struct {
   char ciudad[N];
   double max;
   double min;
   double med;
} T_TEMP_MMM;
```

Tengo que ingresar el clima de todas las ciudades pero en este caso solo seran 2 que se guardaran en `char ciudad[N]` y el clima que se ingresara en `datos[365]` y ya lo hice aquí dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 2

typedef struct {
    char ciudad[N];
    double datos[365];
    int n_datos;
} T_TEMP;

typedef struct {
    char ciudad[N];
    double max;
    double min;
    double med;
} T_TEMP_MMM;

int main() {
    T_TEMP C;
    int i, n=0, j, a=0, b=0;
    principini:
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("ingresa la town: ");
        scanf("%s",&C.ciudad);
        printf("¿ingresaras 365 datos, 53 datos o 12 datos? ");
        scanf("%d",&C.n_datos);
        if(C.n_datos==365){
            for(j=0;j<365;j++){
                n=n+1;
                printf("¿como estuvo el clima del dia %d viejo? ",n);
                scanf("%s",C.datos);
            }
            printf("shido men :v \n\n");
        }
        else if(C.n_datos==53){
            for(j=0;j<53;j++){
                a=a+1;
                printf("¿como estuvo el clima del dia %d viejo? ",a);
                scanf("%s",C.datos);
            }
            printf("shido men :v \n\n");
        }
        else if(C.n_datos==12){
            for(j=0;j<12;j++){
                b=b+1;
                printf("¿como estuvo el clima del dia %d viejo? ",b);
                scanf("%s",C.datos);
            }
            printf("shido men :v \n\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("que no sabes leer >:v solo puedes ingresar 365, 53 o 12 datos ahora iniciaras de nuevo \n\n");
            goto principini;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pero mi duda es que me pide que calcule el clima maximo, el minimo y la media de cada ciudad y no se como enviar los datos de la primer estructura a la otra para poder calcularlo me dice que use estas funciones

```
void GeneraMMM(T_TEMP vec[],int n, T_TEMP_MMM mmm[]);
```

La función anterior debe llamar a la función `Calcula_mmm()` que recibe un vector de temperaturas, calcula y calcula la temperatura máxima, la mínima y la media:

```
void Calcula_mmm(double t[], int n, double *pmax, double *pmin, double *pmed);
```

Escribir el código de las funciones `GeneraMMM()` y `Calcula_mmm()`.

Pero yo pensaba hacerlo todo en el main solo que no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Oh no! Reggaeton hasta en StackOverflow ... espero que los antivirus detecten ese "ingresa la town" y pongan tu programa en cuarentena :P

Comment: lo gracioso es que tengo que desactivar mi antivirus para que se ejecute :"v pero si esto esta mal visto dejare de ponerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un pequeño inciso. Me temo que no has entendido bien el probleama. Si te piden 2 ciudades, no puedes hacer `char ciudad[N]` (con N = 2). Con eso, **no** creas 2 ciudades, sino que reservas 2 caracteres para el nombre de la ciudad.

Tendrías que crear un arreglo de `T_TEMP` y otro de `T_TEMP_MMM`, algo como esto:

```
#define NAME_LENGTH 50

typedef struct {
  char ciudad[NAME_LENGTH];
  double datos[365];
  int n_datos;
} T_TEMP;

typedef struct {
  char ciudad[NAME_LENGTH];
  double max;
  double min;
  double med;
} T_TEMP_MMM;

int main( void ) {
  T_TEMP C[N];
  T_TEMP_MMM M[N];
```

En cuanto a la pregunta, lo que te están pidiendo es que crees una función para calcular los datos y asignarlos; algo como esto:

```
#include <float.h>

void Calcula_mmm( double t[], int n, double *pmax, double *pmin, double *pmed ) {
  int idx;

  *pmax = DBL_MIN;
  *pmin = DBL_MAX;
  *pmed = 0.0;

  for( idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx ) {
    if( t[n] > *pmax )
      *pmax = t[n];

    if( t[n] < *pmin )
      *pmin = t[n];

    *pmed += t[n];
  };

  *pmed /= n;
}
```

A su vez, la función anterior sería llamada desde

```
void GeneraMMM( T_TEMP vec[], int n, T_TEMP_MMM mmm[] ) {
  int idx;

  for( idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx )
    Calcula_mmm( vec[n].datos, vec[n].n_datos, &(mmm[n].max), &(mmm[n].min), &(mmm[n].med ) );
}
```

Que, a su vez, se llamaría desde `main( )` así:

```
GeneraMMM( C, N, m );
```

Por supuesto, al crear arreglos de ciudades, **tendrás que adaptar todo el código** que tienes hecho; tal y como está, no funcionará con arreglos, solo con variables *sueltas*.

**EDITO**

El código completo quedaría asi:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 2 // Número de ciudades.
#define NAME_LENGTH 50 // Longitud máxima nombre de ciudad.

typedef struct {
  char ciudad[NAME_LENGTH];
  double datos[365];
  int n_datos;
} T_TEMP;

typedef struct {
  char ciudad[NAME_LENGTH];
  double max;
  double min;
  double med;
} T_TEMP_MMM;

void Calcula_mmm( double t[], int n, double *pmax, double *pmin, double *pmed ) {
  int idx;

  *pmax = DBL_MIN;
  *pmin = DBL_MAX;
  *pmed = 0.0;

  for( idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx ) {
    if( t[n] > *pmax )
      *pmax = t[n];

    if( t[n] < *pmin )
      *pmin = t[n];

    *pmed += t[n];
  };

  *pmed /= n;
}

void GeneraMMM( T_TEMP vec[], int n, T_TEMP_MMM mmm[] ) {
  int idx;

  for( idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx )
    Calcula_mmm( vec[n].datos, vec[n].n_datos, &(mmm[n].max), &(mmm[n].min), &(mmm[n].med ) );
}

void RellenarCiudad( T_TEMP *C ) {
  int idx;

  printf( "ingresa la town: " );
  scanf( "%s", C->ciudad );

  while( 1 ) {
   printf( "¿ingresaras 365 datos, 53 datos o 12 datos? " );
   scanf( "%d", &( C->n_datos ) );

    if( ( C->n_datos == 365 ) ||
        ( C->n_datos == 53 ) ||
        ( C->n_datos == 12 ) )
      break;

    printf( "que no sabes leer >:v solo puedes ingresar 365, 53 o 12 datos.\n\n" );
  }

  for( idx = 0; idx < C->n_datos; ++idx ) {
    printf( "¿como estuvo el clima del dia %d viejo? ", idx + 1 );
    scanf( "%lf", &( C->datos[idx] ) );
  }

  printf( "shido men :v \n\n" );
}

int main( void ) {
  T_TEMP C[N];
  T_TEMP_MMM M[N];
  int idx;

  for( idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx )
    RellenarCiudad( &( C[idx]) );

  GeneraMMM( C, N, M );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: disculpa amigo ya trate de hacer otro código pero no me queda y trate de juntar el tuyo con el mio y tampoco no se como hacerlo mediante funciones perdon si pregunto esto pero como podria hacer que funcione

Comment: @lalohernandez respuesta editada con el código completo ;-)